# How does Craigslist maps work?

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

Craigslist has a new feature...when you search for things, you can view by map. It places markers (representing postings) on a map and if you click them it shows you a customized listing that shows details about the posting that the marker represents.

CL is using [openstreetmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap).

A couple questions:

1. How does CL do this with the custom markers and the popups etc.?
2. Does google maps have anything similar?

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: http://sfbay.craigslist.org/ppa/#map

Comment: What's with the downvote and close vote?

Answer (score 1):

Craigslist uses [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/) with the [Leaflet MarkerCluster plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster). For obtaining the marker positions craigslist probably uses some geocoder, like [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) or maybe Google.

Comment: No idea, Google Maps is non-free and therefore not within my field of interest. But Leaflet is able to use Google Maps as a tile provider. So Craigslist could display a Google Maps background, too. But I guess they choose OpenStreetMap instead because it's cheaper.